# Executing on a selected node in selenium grid

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, java, browser-automation, selenium-webdriver

I have one scenario i.e.. I have one web view to take all actions(click,send-keys,opening new window) and locator types(ex: xpath,id,name and cssClassName) with these values I am going to create a selenium script and executing using selenium grid (All these things will be happens with the help of servlets).

My Issue : Lets take the sample scenario, I have three machines A,B and C . In the machine A is configured as a server hub and Machine B and C are configured as a Node's . So when I am try to create and execute the selenium script through WebUI(which is explained above) ,the browsers was opening in either machine B or C but I want to open a browser in which machine webUI was used to create a selenium script.Is it possible ???.If yes please let me know

Answer (score 1):

Each node has three configuration items: browserName, version and platform. The version is a "free" format. If you give each of your nodes a made up version name (999,998 and 997) then you can use the Grid capability to force a test the run on the version name of choice.

Start the nodes with

```
 -browser version=999
```

In your test ask for a capability:

```
capability.setVersion("999");
```

If only one node has this version, the test should start the run on that node.

For more info about Grid configration look at: https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/Grid2

Comment: Hello Niels, Thanks for your answer . While using your code ,it's giving a compilation error "The method setPlatform(Platform) in the type DesiredCapabilities is not applicable for the arguments (String)"

Comment: Hmm, think your right, the platforms are not a free format (https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/GridPlatforms), please try the version then, make up a version number. Was a long time ago, but I have done something similar in the past, not sure of all the details.

Comment: Seems there is also an undocumented "applicationName" https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3660

Comment: Hello Niels, some how I achieved to execute on a specific node but it fails with other than my node(localhost).I am not sure it is problem with my hub url (http://ipadress:4444/grid/register) or some thing else ??? please help me

Comment: These are the log messages I can able to see in hub console when I am running from my node(I mean hub and node are located in same machine)

Comment: INFO - Got a request to create a new session: Capabilities [{platform=ANY, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, crazyNodeName=node1, version=}]
10:44:11.161 INFO - Available nodes: [host :http://nodeipaddress:5555]
 INFO - Trying to create a new session on node host :http://nodeipaddress:5555
INFO - Trying to create a new session on test slot {seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, platform=VISTA, browserName=chrome, maxInstances=5, crazyNodeName=node1}

Answer (score 0):

```
        // settings.setBrowserName("firefox");
        settings.setPlatform(Platform.WIN8_1);
        // Node 1 will be Launched with FF in  Windows 8 

        settings.setBrowserName("chrome");
        settings.setPlatform(Platform.LINUX);

        // Node 2 will be launched with Chrome in Linux

        driver = new RemoteWebDriver(hubURL, settings);



        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        // Maximize the Browser
```

Comment: What if the platform and browsers combinations are the same for both nodes, because I think that is the question.